# HTML5 gps inside a WebView

Tags: ios, html, webview, gps

Was curious about something the other day and could not find an answer.. With a native iOS app, if you load a page in a WebView that uses the gps functionality of HTML5, is the user prompted the same way they would be if viewing it in a browser?

(Yes, I know you could use native API if it's already a native app, but curious nonetheless and have no way to perform a test)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will see the same alert, it's a system alert.
However, other than triggered by a native app, the users choice will not be persistent and the alert will be shown on every visit.